# How to search a row to see if any of the columns contain a certain string? In SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with 10 columns that each contain string values. I want to run a query that will return any of the rows which have any column value that matches a given string or set of strings.

Is there any way to do this?

The DBMS is MsSQL

Comment: Please add your DBMS, I.e. Oracle, mssql, MariaDB...

Comment: If you want to match against a set of strings, is order important? Also must the set match against one column or one or more,?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want exact match, you can use IN keyword and check in all columns

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE 'your string' IN (column1, column2, )
```

if you want partial match then you have to use LIKE

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE column1 LIKE '%your string%' or column2 LIKE '%your string%' ...
```

or you can add all columns and do one LIKE check

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE CONCAT(column1,'#',column2,'#',column3,'#',...) LIKE '%your string%'
```

Comment: The CONCAT version doesn't work 100%. (And is also product specific, to a question with no dbms specified.)

Comment: Example: `concat('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC') like '%AB%'` will return TRUE, but there is no actual column having the AB.

Comment: @jarlh, thanks for pointing that out. May be I should give a space between columns. I will make that change

Comment: If using concat, chose a character that will never show up in the data. Perhaps `#`?